# Как в kotlin передать объект через Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-intent, serializable

Я передаю свой объект класса `Photo`:

```
data class Photo(val id: String? = null,
                 val color: String? = null,
                 val created_at: String? = null,
                 val description: String? = null,
                 val downloads: Int? = null): Serializable
```

через Intent следующим образом:

```
intent: Intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(photo, Photo as Serializable)
startActivity(intent)
```

дальше в `MyActivity` я получаю данные передаваемые в `Intent` и помещаю их в `Bundle`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_activity)

    val bundle = intent.extras
}
```

что теперь необходимо сделать что бы получить переданный объект класса `Photo` в `MyActivity`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bundle`, в который складывает значения `Intent` представляет собой ключ-значение хранилище. Чтобы положить значение, нужно указать ключ и само значение:

```
intent.putExtra("photo", photo)
```

Получить значение можно так:

```
val photo = intent.getSerializableExtra("photo") as? Photo // если нет значения с таким ключом, то photo == null
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!